# Add boxplots to a line graph in base R using a seperate data frame

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I want to add boxplots to a line graph in base R.

I have a rather big data set, and I want to create many different plots, which is why I created a subset for every plot I wanted to create.

Here is a very stripped-down version of my problem:

```
cat <- rep(1:10,10)
#create 10 categories

x1 <- rnorm(cat)
x2 <- rnorm(cat)
x3 <- rnorm(cat)
#create 3 X variables


test_data<-data.frame(cat,x1,x2,x3)
#create data frame

cat <- 1:10

plot_data <- data.frame(
  y = cat,
  x1_mean = tapply(test_data$x1,test_data$cat,mean),
  x2_mean = tapply(test_data$x2, test_data$cat,mean),
  x3_mean = tapply(test_data$x3, test_data$cat,mean)
)
#create data frame for plotting
#mean for every x variable per category



plot(plot_data$y,plot_data$x1_mean,type = "b", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", col = "blue", ylim = c((-1),1))  
lines(plot_data$y,plot_data$x2_mean, type = "b",col = "green")
lines(plot_data$y,plot_data$x3_mean, type = "b",col = "red")
#plot means per category
```

I use the data frame `data_plot` to plot my line graph. And it looks like this:
[image]

Now I would like to add a boxplot of the distribution of every x-variable per category (`cat`/`y`).

For this, I probably have to capture the information needed in the boxplot in the data frame `data_plot` and then use it to plot the boxplot.
Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach it.

While the means of the three `x` variables for one category can be placed at the same *x* coordinate (1 to 10), the boxplots should be drawn at different *x* coordinates not to cover one another. This could be done using a loop over the three `x` variables or by transforming the data into long format with a single `x` variable and another variable indicating to which `cat`/`x` the value belongs. We will go with the latter approach.

```r
# put all x variables in one column
test_data_long <- reshape(test_data, direction="long", varying=list(2:4), 
                          v.names="x", timevar="xn")
# category and variant of x (xn) together for placing boxplots along the x axis
test_data_long$cat2 <- with(test_data_long, cat + (xn - 2)/5)
# reorder so that boxplots are drawn in the correct order
test_data_long <- test_data_long[order(test_data_long$cat2), ]
```

The first command just transforms the data into long format with a single `x` variable and an `xn` variable which indicates the original index of `x` (`x`**1**, `x`**2**, `x`**3**).

Then we create the `cat2` variable which distinguishes between `xn` within `cat` and is used as the *x* coordinate for the boxplots. We want to have `x2` values exactly at `cat` (1, 2, ..., 10), `x1` values to the left (0.8, 1.8, ..., 9.8) and `x2` values to the right (1.2, 2.2, ..., 10.2), which is achieved with `cat + (xn - 2) / 5`. This spacing is specifically for three `x` variables (`max(xn)` = 3) and generally it could be something like `cat + (xn - (max(xn) + 1)/2) / (max(xn) + 2)`.

Next we just need to reorder the data according to `cat2` so that the boxplots are drawn in the same order the *x* values we will provide are in.

And now the plotting itself. With different layers of information in one plot I like to suppress the less important ones with transparency.

```r
xn_col <- palette()[4:2]
box_col <- xn_col[unique(test_data_long$xn)]
# draw boxplots in semi-transparent colors
par(mar=c(4.5, 4.5, .5, .5))
boxplot(x ~ cat2, test_data_long, at=unique(test_data_long$cat2), 
        boxwex=.15, xaxt='n', xlab='cat',
        border=paste0(box_col, '66'), col=paste0(box_col, '11'))
axis(1, at=unique(test_data$cat))

# compute mean values
data_mean <- aggregate(. ~ cat, test_data, mean)
# draw semi-transparent points under the means to make them pop out more
sapply(data_mean[, -1], points, x=data_mean$cat, 
       pch=16, col='#ffffffcc', cex=2)
# draw mean values
for (cat in 1:3) {
  lines(data_mean$cat, data_mean[[paste0('x', cat)]], type='b', 
        col=xn_col[cat], lwd=1.7, cex=1.2)
}
```

[image: boxplots]

Comment: Could you elaborate on your thinking behind the restructuring of the data? 
`# put all x variables in one column
test_data_long <- reshape(test_data, direction="long", varying=list(2:4), 
                          v.names="x", timevar="xn")
# category and variant of x (xn) together for placing boxplots along the x axis
test_data_long$cat2 <- with(test_data_long, cat + (xn - 2)/5)
# reorder so that boxplots are drawn in the correct order
test_data_long <- test_data_long[order(test_data_long$cat2), ]
box_col <- xn_col[unique(test_data_long$xn)]`
I can't quite follow your thinking there.

Comment: @Linus No problem, I added some more explanations. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Linus. It is way easier and prettier to do it with `ggplot2` which is a total upgrade of `plot`. No manual calculation is needed at all.

```
#transform data from wide to long
plot_data%<>%gather(x_n, x, x1_mean:x3_mean)
    y     x_n           x
1   1 x1_mean  0.07693024
2   2 x1_mean -0.13028139
3   3 x1_mean -0.42961166
4   4 x1_mean -0.34407245
5   5 x1_mean -0.35282387
6   6 x1_mean  0.03674028
7   7 x1_mean  0.11697250
8   8 x1_mean  0.08043970
9   9 x1_mean -0.13349448
10 10 x1_mean  0.30147798
11  1 x2_mean  0.67541081
12  2 x2_mean -0.01736939
...
30 10 x3_mean -0.20983470

#ggplot in one go
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = `y`, y= `x`, col=x_n))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=y), alpha=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I was looking for something else.  I want a separate boxplot for every x-variable. The distribution of the x-variable is in the original data set ´test_data´.  So three boxplots per category.
I'm not the biggest fan of ´ggplot2´, so I'm looking for a way to do it with ´plot´.